# Can I create a reference to a class in C#

Tags: c#

In my code I set up two different data sources:

```
_dslocal = new XXX("local"); <- example only
_dsremote = new XXX("remote"); <- example only
```

Later in the code I retrieve data with a long select that looks similar to this:

```
var _rowData = (from question in _dslocal.GetAll() <- example only
                ... many lines of code
```

What I would like to do is to allow a user to switch between local and remote. I
don't want to have something like:

```
if ( switch == "local" ) {
  var _rowData = (from question in _dslocal.GetAll() <- example only
                ... many lines of code

} else {
  var _rowData = (from question in _dsremote.GetAll() <- example only
                ... many lines of code
}
```

Maybe this is not a good question but can I do this:

```
if ( switch == "local" ) {
  var _source = _dslocal;
} else {
  var _source = _dsremote;
}
var _rowData = (from question in _source.GetAll() <- example only
                ... many lines of code
```

Comment: Don't optimize an if() statement.

Comment: @Hans: It all depends on what you are trying to optimize. I agree that this might be a bad way to achieve optimal *performance* but I think the OP is more interested in optimal *code readability*. Also they were unsure if it was wise to create multiple references to the same object.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can absolutely do this. There are also some options that might make the code a bit cleaner and easier to read. In your case I would create a method like this:

```
DataSource GetDataSource(string switch)
{
    return switch == "local" ? _dslocal : _dsremote;
}
```

Then your LINQ code can be a lot cleaner:

```
var _source = GetDataSource(switch);
var _rowData = (from question in _source.GetAll());
```

I once heard Jon Skeet refer to references that point to objects like strings on a balloon. Any given balloon (object) can have many strings (references) attached to it.  Feel free to create as many references to that object as you need but remember that the references themselves are not the object and if you use the reference to change the object all other references will see that change as well since they are all pointing at the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Even better, you can do this:

```
XXX _source;

if ( switch == "local" ) {
  _source = new XXX("local");
} else {
  _source = new XXX("remote");
}
```

Or even, perhaps:

```
var source = new XXX(switch);
```